# random list within a certain limit

Tags: python, list, random

i want to generate a random list, in which generates n numbers between a and b. However, when executing, nothing comes out.

```
def random_list(a,b,n):
    import random
    xs=[]
    x=random.randint(a,b)
    xs.append(x)
    while len(xs)==n:
        return xs
```

Comment: You probably wanted to do `while len(xs) != n:`  for the loop.

Comment: Nothing is supposed to come out of your code. You do not have a print statement there.

Comment: print statement is not mandatory, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one (using `randint` with list comprehension to generate the random list)

```
import random

def random_list(a,b,n):
    xs = [random.randint(a,b) for _ in range(n)]
    return xs
```

**output:**

```
>>> print(random_list(1, 10, 4))
[6, 2, 6, 4]

>>> print(random_list(1, 10, 4))
[3, 9, 2, 1]
```

---

If you wish to keep the `while` loop, you could re-arrange your code to something like this:

```
import random

def random_list(a,b,n):
    xs=[]
    while len(xs) < n:
        x = random.randint(a,b)
        xs.append(x)
    return xs
```

Answer (score 1):

A small change in logic and small code move should fix it.

```py
def random_list(a,b,n):
    import random
    xs=[]
    while len(xs)!=n:
        x=random.randint(a,b)
        xs.append(x)
        return xs
```

Also as others have mentioned, if you aware of list comprehension then please use them. That will make code much cleaner.